# Debugging large number of crash reports from a smart phone app

Tags: android, ios, debugging, windows-phone, crash-reports

I am developer of a mobile app. Recently, we have just released a mobile application and we started to receive a large number of crash traces, many are duplicate. Manual investigation and grouping
of these similar reports has become very time consuming. What are the best practices and tools that are typically used to manage and expedite this process? Is there any tool that can help locating the faulty functions?

Comment: Have you tried Crashlytics?

Comment: Yes Crashlytics makes this so easy and gives you nice symbolicated reports as well to organize them for you.

Comment: Also it's free (owned by twitter).

Comment: I looked at Crashlytics. Any idea about the accuracy of these features provided by Crashlytics: 1) smart grouping of crashes and 2) highlighting of interesting and uninteresting lines in the stack traces?
Is it possible to analyze our previously collected crash traces, e.g., by uploading them to Crashlytics?

Comment: Ever think about fixing the app?

Comment: We are definitely trying to fix the bugs. However, bug prioritization and grouping of duplicate bugs are vital components within the software maintenance pipeline to reduce cost and time. For instance, we don't want to spend resources on duplicate crash reports from users who don't update the app automatically; but instead focus on new ones.

Answer (score 0):

If it is windows store app, you can use the DebugDiag. More information is available in the below blog.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/26/automating-analysis-of-windows-store-crash-reports.aspx